# Problem with VMWare Tools drag & drop

Tags: virtualization

I installed VMWare Tools in ElementaryOS 0.4 but some features seem missing.

Shared Folders work perfectly but my mouse is restricted in the virtual machine and I can't drag & drop any files from host to guest.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the VMWare Fusion environment for Mac, pressing "Command" + "Control" keys simultaneously will release the mouse cursor to normal use outside the virtual machine window even if VMWare Tools is not installed.

The "Drag and Drop" feature is a basic feature of VMWare Tools. The fact that this feature is not working may indicate that Tools failed to install correctly.

Copy and uncompress "Tools" for Linux into Loki's Home/Downloads folder

open Terminal
use the `cd` command to change directory to the one containing the uncompressed `vmware-install.pl` file.

Use this command to install Tools manually:

```
sudo perl vmware-install.pl
```

(supply admin password required for `sudo`), answer subsequent prompts with Enter key to accept defaults for "Tools" installation.

Comment: Thanks for your help:) I tried installing Linux in both VMWare Fusion and Parallels Desktop and all features are available. But when I install some Linux distributions with EFI mode in VMWare on a Windows host, Drag&Drop is unusable. Legacy BIOS mode is ok and I don't why :(